# CSS float and div block position

Tags: css, positioning, html, css-float

I have this problem then I try to float div left,
each block contains same div class (member).

Block goes up if it is on the right hand side, but doesnt work on left.

Any thoughts?

```
.member {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 422px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[image: example]

[image with example](http://mg-web.co.uk/hosting/bugs/member2.jpg)

Comment: Post your HTML, please. It depends on order of these blocks.

Comment: mg-web.co.uk/hosting/bugs/html_css/team.htm - I am getting really confused, there could be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want two columns with blocks of different height.

Then you should one column float to left and the second to the right:

Like this:

```
.member {
    position: relative;
    width: 422px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    height: auto;
}

.fl_left {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.fl_right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <div class="fl_left">
        <div class="member"></div>
        <div class="member"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right">
        <div class="member"></div>
        <div class="member"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [link](http://mg-web.co.uk/hosting/bugs/html_css/team2.htm) - Yes but in this case block on the left dont go up, I dont need the spacing between the divs